# Dynamically setting base href not working for child routes

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app on version 15.2 in an Nx workspace that uses standalone components.

When hardcoding the base href in the index.html file, I'm able to navigate to each route in my app and do a full page reload on each route without a problem. It works exactly as expected, but I need to have different base hrefs for each environment that I deploy to, so I tried setting the base href dynamically with `APP_BASE_HREF`, but that resulted in problems on child routes.

I tried setting my base href dynamically in my main.ts file, like so:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: renderBaseHref(),
    },
    ...
  ]
})
```

This approach appeared to work at first. I can navigate to any route within the app, but full page reloads do not work while on child routes. For example, when the route is something like /my-app/page1, it will load fine, but after navigating to /my-app/page1/12345, a full page reload will result in 404s on a bunch of files, like this:

> /my-app/page1/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

The path it should be looking for (and does look for when NOT on a child route) is /my-app/main.js

I also tried hardcoding `useValue` to '/my-app/' to see if there was an issue with my `renderBaseHref` method, but I got the same exact results.

How can I get `APP_BASE_HREF` to work on all of my routes the same way it works when I hardcode the base href in my index.html file?

Comment: I think you'd also need to change the <base> tag in the index dynamically maybe using a script embedded int the index.html as well. Otherwise the browser does not know where to load the scripts from.

Comment: Isn't that ultimately what providing `APP_BASE_HREF` is supposed to be doing? It knows where to load the scripts from when I reload a top level route. It's only when I'm on a child route that it attempts to load from the wrong route.

I tried adding `document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href = baseHref` to a script tag in the index.html file and I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: The error in your question is caused before the APP_BASE_HREF provider is set. The browser doe not know where the scripts are located. I thought setting the base might help, but was not sure, that's why i commented. In my case, we have separate builds for each environment setting the --baseHref parameter.